# Elasticsearch - Migrate lndex from Windows machine to Linux machine

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, migration

We are currently running ES on Windows 2012 R2 server machine (In-house) and it has total **20 Million** Documents with  **12 GB** of index size.

Now we are called to migrate our Windows server into Linux Server. In order to that I am seeking any reliable method to ship Index data from Windows to Linux machine. Can anyone please suggest the best workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't copy the data directory! Choose a supported path:**

1. [CCR](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-ccr.html) - the easiest and fastest if you have both cluster platinum licensed
2. [Snapshot via FS/S3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshot-restore.html) - if you have snapshots already in place, a good option, especially with [S3 as storage](https://hub.docker.com/r/minio/minio/) as you don't need to copy the snapshot to the new nodes or mount on all data nodes in both clusters. This is also a fast option as you don't reindex in the destination cluster - it's just a fast restore of shards and probably the second-best approach in term of speed.
3. [Reindex from remote](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#reindex-from-remote) - comes with the overhead of reindexing the docs but works also with different elasticsearch versions, if you want a simple way or need to update the elastic version to newer major version, try this way
4. Logstash with elasticsearch [input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html) and [output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) - Same as 3.) but with logstash in between. An easy path if you want to modify the docs while copying

Good luck!